# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined REACT

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html-table, fetch

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        lista: [],
    }
}      

componentDidMount(){
    fetch('http://lospraianos-env-1.qu3skpxsmw.sa-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/materials')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(resData => {
        this.setState( {data: resData.results});
      })

}

<div>
  <table className="pure-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>Produto</th>
        <th>Quantidade</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
        <tbody>{
          this.props.lista.map(function(data){
            return (  
              <tr key={data.codMat}>
                <td>{data.codMat}</td>
                <td>{data.material}</td>
                <td>{data.qntMin}</td>
              </tr>
              );
            })
            }
        </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get info from the API and make a table with it but I'm getting some errors.

> Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

how can I deal with it?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend doing a conditional rendering here, by checking `lista` property first, before mapping all data.

```
{
          this.props.lista && this.props.lista.map(function(data){
            return (  
              <tr key={data.codMat}>
                <td>{data.codMat}</td>
                <td>{data.material}</td>
                <td>{data.qntMin}</td>
              </tr>
              );
            })
            }
```

As well as you have a error in

```
this.setState( {data: resData.results});
```

As you need to set state for `lista:resData.results`, not `data`

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with your codes. Try to fix these:

```
 constructor(props) {  //fixed
    super(props);  //fixed
    this.state = {
      lista: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(
      'http://lospraianos-env-1.qu3skpxsmw.sa-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/materials'
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(resData => {
        this.setState({ lista: resData.results });   //fixed
      });
  }
```

and...

```
  {
    this.state.lista.length > 0 && this.state.lista.map(function(data) {   //fixed
      return (
        <tr key={data.codMat}>
          <td>{data.codMat}</td>
          <td>{data.material}</td>
          <td>{data.qntMin}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    })
  }
```

Comment: yeah the whole problem was actually the setState! thanks man!

Comment: @GabrielTeixeira I'm glad to hear that

Answer (score 2):

You are setting response to a state variable data which doesn’t exist in your code. You need to set it to lista instead of data in fetch Api call like

```
    this.setState({lista : resData.results});
```

And here do conditional check and do .map

.map without return

```
  <tbody>{
      this.props.lista && this.props.lista.map(data => (
          <tr key={data.codMat}>
            <td>{data.codMat}</td>
            <td>{data.material}</td>
            <td>{data.qntMin}</td>
          </tr>
        ))
        }
    </tbody>
```

.map with return

```
  <tbody>{
      this.props.lista && this.props.lista.map(data => {
          return (<tr key={data.codMat}>
            <td>{data.codMat}</td>
            <td>{data.material}</td>
            <td>{data.qntMin}</td>
          </tr>)
        })
        }
    </tbody>
```

Comment: You are welcome. Kindly do upvote and accept which ever solution helped you resolving the issue. So that it will help future readers

Answer (score 1):

You're setting this.`state`.lista to contain array data.

You're trying to map over this.`props`.lista.

this.state !== this.props.

Change `this.props.lista.map` to `this.state.lista.map` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you've set the initial state with that array `lista[]`. Do you have one array like that passed as a prop as well? If yes check for typos and you might also want to use the constructor with the `props` argument that you will pass in the super call like so

```
constructor(props){
     super(props);
     .......
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as i can see, there are 2 problems with the given code,

the first one:

You are running the `Array.prototype.map()` on `this.props.lista`, when the actual array is `this.state.lista`

Also, `componentDidMount()` runs after the `render()` function,
so either move the `fetch()` to the `constructor` or set a condition for you map function

Read https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#mounting for better understanding of React.component's lifecycles