# How to resolve " Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" error in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm following a React JS tutorial and I'm attempting to pass props from one component to another in order to render a list of tracks. I've looked at few threads with similar issues but none of the suggestions have resolved my issue and I'm at a loss. I suspect the issue has something to do with how my initial state is set.

I've attempted the following.

[Cannot read property 'map' of undefined REACT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52722680/cannot-read-property-map-of-undefined-react)

- Changing 'this.props' to 'this.state' and vise versa on receiving components as recommended above but this does not resolve the issue and just returns 'cannot read property tracks of null'

This is my  App.js where initial state is defined and passed to the search results component

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      searchResults: [
        {
          name:'test', 
          artist:'test',
          album: 'test',
          id:'2'
        },
        {
          name:'test', 
          artist:'test',
          album: 'test',
          id:'2'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (

      <div>
      <h1>Ja<span className="highlight">mmm</span>ing</h1>
      <div className="App">
        <SearchBar/>
        <div className="App-playlist">
          <SearchResults searchResults={this.state.searchResults}/>
          <Playlist/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



  );
  }
}
export default App;
```

This is where the SearchResults component passes props to TrackList

```
class SearchResults extends React.Component { 
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="SearchResults">
            <h2>Results</h2>
                <TrackList tracks = {this.props.searchResults}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default SearchResults;
```

This is where the error seems to be occurring.

```
class TrackList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="TrackList">
        {this.state.tracks.map(track => <Track key={track.id} 
        track={track}  />)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TrackList;
```

Lastly the track class that should render a track

```
class Track extends React.Component { 
    render(){

        return( 
                        <div className="Track">
            <div className="Track-information">
                <h3>{this.props.track.name}</h3>
                <p> {this.props.track.artist} | {this.props.track.album}</p>
            </div>
            <button className="Track-action">- + or - will go here --></button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Track;
```

the output should be a rendered list of tracks, instead I get 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
>   TrackList.render
>   src/components/TrackList/TrackList.js:11
>      8 | class TrackList extends React.Component {
>      9 |   render() {
>     10 |     return (
>   11 |       
>     12 |         {this.props.tracks.map(track => )}
>     14 |

Comment: It should be `this.props.tracks` in `TrackList component instead of `this.state.tracks`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be:

```
{this.props.tracks.map(track => <Track key={track.id} track={track}  />)}
```

change `state` to `props`

Answer (score 1):

**Comment out the TrackList component from the PlayList render() method** and it should work.

I am doing this same course from codecademy. The reason you still got the error is because in PlayList.js there is a TrackList component being rendered there but without any props. So in the TrackList class, there is no props to map.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually setting the property `tracks` in the `TrackList` component here:

```
<TrackList tracks = {this.props.searchResults}/>
```

`tracks` here is not a state, it is a property of the component (i.e. `props`).
So you may want to change the following line:

```
{this.state.tracks.map(track => <Track key={track.id}
```

To:

```
{this.props.tracks.map(track => <Track key={track.id}
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: Hi there, despite making the suggested changes I'm facing the same error. Any thoughts?

Comment: This might be a long shot, perhaps remove the spaces between the "=".
i.e. `<TrackList tracks={this.props.searchResults}/>`.
If that doesn't solve it work backwards. Try to confirm that the values are indeed being passed down by making `searchResults` a local variable immediately after the render() and before the return in the App.js. i.e. 
`render() { const searchResults: [...]; return (`
And pass it in directly:
`<SearchResults searchResults={searchResults}/>`

Comment: You may also need to consider using the `componentDidMount()` and `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)` events in the reactjs pipeline. Usually `constructor(props)` is used for initializing `this.state` and the component then gets "mounted" and can set state by calling `this.setState()`. There is more information here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Answer (score 0):

First console `this.props.searchResults` on SearchResult Component then console `this.props.tracks` in TrackList Component , then 
Replace

```
 {this.state.tracks.map(track => <Track key={track.id}
```

To

```
{this.props.tracks && this.props.tracks.map(track => <Track key={track.id}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your TrackList component, you should use `this.props.tracks.map....` instead of `this.state.tracks.map...` because you passed the data to this component as a value of `tracks` prop.

```
class TrackList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="TrackList">
        {this.props.tracks.map(track => <Track key={track.id} 
        track={track} 
      />)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TrackList;
```